# How to get the drive letter of an SD Card connected to a PC, using C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, wmi, sd-card

How to get the drive letter of an SD Card connected to a PC, from a C# .NET Framework application?

I have looked at suggested questions on this topic, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462264), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790606) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790606), but none of them give me the solution I need.

Using System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives() or System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher() with query "Win32_LogicalDisk", I can get the drive letters of all devices, but I can't tell which device(s) is the SD card.
Using System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher() with query "CIM_LogicalDevice", "Caption = 'SDHC Card'", I get 2 devices with the "SDHC Card" caption property, but no drive letters.

How can I get the drive letter of the SD Card or card reader?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace Code3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tfrom: 'ManagementObjectSearcher()' with query \"Win32_LogicalDisk\"");
            var searcher1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\root\cimv2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");
            foreach (ManagementBaseObject disk in searcher1.Get())
            {
                string diskID = disk.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID").ToString();
                int driveType = Convert.ToInt32(disk.GetPropertyValue("DriveType"));
                string diskCaption = disk.GetPropertyValue("Caption").ToString();
                string diskDescription = disk.GetPropertyValue("Description").ToString();
                string diskName = disk.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
                int diskMediaType = Convert.ToInt32(disk.GetPropertyValue("MediaType"));
                Console.WriteLine($"{diskName} - ID: {diskID},  Caption: {diskCaption},  Desc.: {diskDescription,-16},  Drive Type: {driveType},  Media Type: {diskMediaType}.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\tfrom: 'ManagementObjectSearcher()' with query SelectQuery(\"CIM_LogicalDevice\", \"Caption = 'SDHC Card'\")");
            ManagementScope mgmtScope = new ManagementScope(@"\root\cimv2");
            SelectQuery devQuery = new SelectQuery("CIM_LogicalDevice", "Caption = 'SDHC Card'");
            var searcher2 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mgmtScope, devQuery);

            foreach (ManagementBaseObject device in searcher2.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{device.GetPropertyValue("Name"),-15} - Caption: {device.GetPropertyValue("Caption")},  Device ID: {device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID")}.");
                continue; // ... to skip property display

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(device.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString()))
                {
                    PropertyDataCollection props = device.Properties;
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n\t\tProperties of {device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID")} Drive: \n");
                    foreach (var prop in device.Properties)
                    {
                        if (prop.Value != null)
                            Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name,-20} - {prop.Type,-8} - {prop.Value ?? "(null)"}");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

EDIT:
From "CIM_LogicalDisk", I can see that "F:" drive is my SD-Card. (from 'VolumeName' property.)

From "CIM_LogicalDevice", I can see the "\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1" and "PCISTOR\DISK&VEN_RSPER&PROD_RTS5208LUN0&REV_1.00\0000" is my SD-Card. (from 'Name', 'Caption', and/or 'Model' properties.)

But my app can't see this! Note that 'drive letter' and 'PHYSICALDRIVE number' do not remain correlated, and can change as different removable devices are inserted and removed.

How can I get my code to make the connection between logical and physical drives?

Comment: The card should have a label so you can tell the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solution worked out. Using WMI association classes, I was able to make the connection between logical and physical drives.

This class is my solution:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;

namespace GetSDCard
{
    public class GetSDCards
    {
        public Card[] GetCards()
        {
            return FindCards().ToArray();
        }

        private List<Card> FindCards()
        {
            List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();

            //  Get Disk Drives collection (Win32_DiskDrive)
            string queryDD = "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Caption = 'SDHC Card'";
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searchDD = new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryDD))
            {
                ManagementObjectCollection colDiskDrives = searchDD.Get();
                foreach (ManagementBaseObject objDrive in colDiskDrives)
                {
                    //  Get associated Partitions collection (Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition)
                    string queryPart = $"ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='{objDrive["DeviceID"]}'}} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
                    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searchPart = new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryPart))
                    {
                        ManagementObjectCollection colPartitions = searchPart.Get();
                        foreach (ManagementBaseObject objPartition in colPartitions)
                        {
                            //  Get associated Logical Disk collection (Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition)
                            string queryLD = $"ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='{objPartition["DeviceID"]}'}} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition";
                            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searchLD = new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryLD))
                            {
                                ManagementObjectCollection colLogicalDisks = searchLD.Get();
                                foreach (ManagementBaseObject objLogicalDisk in colLogicalDisks)
                                    cards.Add(new Card($"{objLogicalDisk["DeviceID"]}", $"{objDrive["Caption"]}", $"{objLogicalDisk["VolumeName"]}"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return cards;
        }


        public class Card
        {
            public string Drive { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Label { get; set; }

            public Card(string _drive, string _name, string _label)
            {
                Drive = _drive;
                Name = _name;
                Label = _label;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a simple console app to demonstrate how to use it.

```
using GetSDCard;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FindSDCard_Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetSDCards getter = new GetSDCards();
            GetSDCards.Card[] sdCards = getter.GetCards();
            if (sdCards.Length == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("No SD Cards found.");
            else
            {
                string sdDrive = sdCards[0].Drive;
                Console.WriteLine($"Root folder of SD Card '{sdDrive}':");
                foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(sdDrive))
                    Console.WriteLine($"\t{folder}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that this can save you the hours of frustration I went through.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really sure that your SD card's volume label is always "SDHC Card" (which I am not), then you can use the following approach:

The [`DriveInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo?view=net-5.0) class contains a static method [`GetDrives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=net-5.0) which returns an array of `DriveInfo` instances. Each instance itself represents on logical drive. You can use the [`VolumeLabel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.volumelabel?view=net-5.0) property to check the name of the volume.

So something like...

```
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(drive => drive.VolumeLabel == "SDHC Card");
```

...returns all drives where the volume is called "SDHC Card".
If you want to get the drive letter of the logical drive you can access it by using the [`RootDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.rootdirectory?view=net-5.0) property of a concrete instance.

Like:

```
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(drive => drive.VolumeLabel == "SDHC Card");

foreach (var drive in drives)
    Console.WriteLine(drive.RootDirectory.FullName);
```

Comment: Markus, you are correct. since my app will be used with new (possibly unformatted?) SD cards from various makers, DriveInfo has no reliable indicator for SD cards. Thanks.